# Hide body until loaded, jQuery fadeout instead of javascript hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to hide a client's page until it's loaded:

```
<style type="text/css">

#cover {position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; top:0; left: 0; background: #1984B5; z-index:9999;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = hide;
function hide(){
nav1=document.getElementById('cover').style
nav1.display='none';
}
</script>
```

But the transition is a little jarring with javascript hide. I'd like to use the jQuery fadeout, but it looks like they've redefined the jQuery `$` as `jQuery`, and I'm not sure how to rewrite this so it works. I tried replacing `$` with `jQuery`, but that didn't work:

```
$("#cover").fadeOut(5000);
```

Comment: jQuery('#cover').fadeOut(5000) should do the trick. $ is just the namespace. Check whether your jQuery script is loaded before the call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the same thing on my site.  Here's my code (essentially identical to yours):

```
<script src="Content/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cover').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
</script>
```

I've got some other content loading dynamically via AJAX after the load as well, so the delay allows me to also give that enough time to render.  But I agree with the other answer: make sure that your jQuery script is loaded first and be sure to put the `fadeOut` line in your `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Do you have any problems with the page flickering before being hidden in IE?

Comment: What version of IE are you using? I did have that issue at one point when I was trying to implement something like we're talking about.  But that was because I had jQuery dynamically create a "cover" div on page load rather than hide an existing top-level div on load.

Comment: Ah, my bad, Chrome, not IE. I'm getting a flicker in Chrome whenever the page is opened from an email link. You can see a glimpse of the page for a fraction of a second before it is hidden.

Comment: Nevermind. I needed to place the code further up on the page.

Comment: UPDATE: ah. okay.  glad it worked. disregard the following then: @miles I'm not quite sure of the cause, but you might be able to avoid this by putting the main content of your site in a separate `div` wrapper and then setting its style to `display:none`.  Then on your `$(document).ready()` function, you can not only `fadeOut` your cover `div` but also `fadeIn` your content `div`.  Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your javascript files are not loaded at that point, so your $ or jQuery is undefined.